# Obtaining the Google Advertising Id

Tags: android, google-advertising-id

I have an App on the PlayStore.

How do I go about:

A. Getting a list of all the Google Advertising Id's for users that have downloaded my app?

B. The link here talks about a "straightforward API" - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en but a redirect occurs and the correct document seems to be missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A. You'll have to retrieve each Google Advertising ID yourself.

B. Its in the Google Play Services API: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient